# Getting Ids that have value all the same

Tags: sql, join, count

I have a table that has been left-joined from user Ids and another value:

```
+ - - - - - - - - - +
¦ Id      ¦  Code   ¦
+ - - - - + - - - - +
¦ 1       ¦     0   ¦
+ - - - - + - - - - +
¦ 1       ¦     1   ¦
+ - - - - + - - - - +
¦ 2       ¦     2   ¦
+ - - - - + - - - - + 
¦ 2       ¦     2   ¦
+ - - - - + - - - - + 
¦ 3       ¦     1   ¦
+ - - - - + - - - - + 
¦ 3       ¦     1   ¦
+ - - - - + - - - - +
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will return the Ids that have all Codes the same value.

So the `Id`'s where all `Code=1` should return `3` only, and not `1` because it has a `0` `Code` somewhere.

I am using this to get all Id's that have all code values the same, except I need to specify only code value of 1:

```
SELECT Id, COUNT(distinct Code) AS CodeGroups
FROM @groupedUsersTable 
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(distinct Code) = 1
```

Comment: just say `where Code=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(CODE) CODE, COUNT(1) CNT
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MAX(CODE) = MIN(CODE) AND MAX(CODE) = 1
```

Not sure the part after the AND is part of what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks. This was the first one that I read that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @id INT
SET @id = 1 -- Code to search for
SELECT DISTINCT
    Id
FROM
    CodeTable t1
WHERE
    Code = @id
    AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CodeTable t2 WHERE t2.Id = t1.Id AND t2.Code <> @id)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is also a solution. However I saw the accepted answer first :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to go from other side, find all records that don't meet requirements and exclude them:

```
SELECT distinct ID FROM tbl 
WHERE tbl.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY ID,CODE
HAVING CODE != 1)
```

DEMO [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c456/26)